# show php results on html page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this php:

```
    $sql = mysql_query("select * from asset where 
                                 name like '%$search%' or 
                                 barcode like '%$search%' or
                                 serial like '%$search%' ");  

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  

        echo '<br/> Name: '.$row['name'];
        echo '<br/> Barcode: '.$row['barcode'];
        echo '<br/> Serial: '.$row['serial']; 

        }
```

and it shows up on a page called search.php, however, I want the file to redirect to a static html page showing the echoed text

Comment: Static is no PHP, Hence the static.

Comment: is there no way to generate one?

Comment: Do you want to send the result to other page?

Comment: generate a static html page with the contents

Comment: Have you tried passing the values along to the required page as a `GET` variable?

Comment: no, that sounds like what I need to do, I just don't know how

Comment: You can generate a new file and redirect to it, but unless you are absolutely sure that you need it, you're most likely to be better off with another solution.

Comment: Why is it that you can't use `search.php` as it is already?

Comment: because I'm working on a phonegap project which needs to consist of only html, javascript & css

Comment: You can't generate PHP within static HTML. I'm not sure if PhoneGap allows JS frameworks. Does it?

Comment: yes, html, css & javascript

Comment: Maybe something like ember.js might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the result in an array and redirect to other page passing this array. May be like this-

```
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  
    array_push($results, $row);
}
$result_json = json_encode($results);
header('Location: {my-html}?results='.$result_json);
```

Then in your html, get this string and manipulate it accordingly.